# Write data to an Excel Sheet using xlsxwriter in Python

Tags: python, selenium, xlsxwriter

I am looking for a clean way to write data to an spreadsheet using xlsxwriter.

The script I have written in Python uses Selenium to cycle through various Facebook pages I oversee and copies the metrics for the past 7 days.

Here's what I have right now:

```
 # Navigate to metrics pages
for link in pages:
    browser.get(f'https://www.facebook.com/{link}/insights/?section=navVideos')

    browser.implicitly_wait(60)

# find_elements_by_class_name - Returns the div in which the metrics are found
    elements = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('_2v66')

    for e in elements:
        print(e.text)
```

Here is what my output looks right now:

[image: Metrics Output]

Is there a streamlined way to output these results in an Excel Sheet using xlsxwriter?

The final script will run for more than 50 pages, the example is only showing the results for two pages. In other words, each page has two pieces of data.

Comment: why don't you open the file in writing mode before the for loop, in each loop you write in the file and when the loop finish you close the file.
https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial01.html

Comment: What would be a good syntax to write on a new line each time? Using something such as i = i + 1 in the loop?

Comment: the for loop that u have is better but instead than print the element you write it in the file ;)